# [recurrence](n) = [recurrence-relation](n)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Nearly identical descriptions:

[recurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recurrence):

> A recurrence relation is an equation that recursively defines a sequence, once one or more initial terms are given: each further term of the sequence is defined as a function of the preceding terms.

[recurrence-relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recurrence-relation):

> In mathematics, a recurrence relation is an equation that recursively defines a sequence, once one or more initial terms are given: each further term of the sequence is defined as a function of the preceding terms.

Comment: And that text itself is plagiarized from any of a number of places, including [here](http://everythingcomputerscience.com/discrete_mathematics/Recurrence_Relations.html)

Comment: I would argue that both tags should die completely - half of the questions tagged with either are actually about recursion and most of the rest are more or less irrelevant to the question except in reference to the fact that they contain some kind of iterative process.

Comment: Yeah, probably a question that ought to be tagged with one of these ought to be asked on [computerscience.SE] instead of SO.

Comment: Shouldn't this be called `Merging [[recurrence]-relation]`?

Comment: @KyleStrand: There, I fixed it =)

Comment: @Claudiu Yours is better!